# Extend a data structure functionality on python

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary on python:

```
structure = dict()
```

and I would like to know how I could achieve something like that:

```
structure.my_func(parameters);
```

Where `my_func` is my custom function.

So I in some way extend it's functionality, I knew we could do that in javascript with prototypes.

Is it possible on python? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define a subclass of the python `dict` class. This subclass can then have your custom attributes and methods.

Comment: @DavidWierichs would you have an example? I'm really not familiar with python...

Comment: Simply extend `dict`: `class my_dict(dict):`

Comment: I think this is very well web-searchable. If you run into concrete problems while realising your idea, post them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, define a subclass of the python `dict` class:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def my_method(self):
        # do what you want here
```

Comment: Thank you!, if i were to do that, would I have to declare my structure as a `MyDict`?

Comment: No, thats just an example. Chose any class name that suits your needs

Comment: let's say I wanted to keep my statement as `structure = dict()` would I be able to do `structure.my_method(params)` or would I have to change my declaration to `structure = MyDict()`?

Comment: of course you must use `structure = MyDict()` otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Python provides the `collections.abc` module to help a programmer to define a custom container. You should use `collection.abc.Mapping` for a read only container, or `collection.abc.MutableMapping` for a mutable one.

Depending on the use case, it can be simpler to inherit from those abstract base classes than directly from a true `dict`.